# How do I fix the I2C HID Device (Code 10) error in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, touchpad

I'm having problems with my **Predator Helios 300 laptop touchpad**. It sometimes works for a short period of time, but then it stops working for several months.

The error message I'm getting is **"Error 10."**

[image: Error in device properties]

I've tried the following to fix the problem:

```
1.Updated Windows
2.Updated to Windows 11 (I dont have any restore points anymore)
3.Updated the driver from Acer's website, but that didn't work/there werent any visible results.
4.Checked the BIOS, but I couldnt find any touchpad there.
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if a factory reset is worth it to have my touchpad back. I have alot of libraries and applications that I have installed and it might affect how my code runs. I have a current project that I'm working on.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me solve this problem. The touchpad is essential for me because I often take my laptop outside and it is a hassle to carry a mouse with me. ‍

Comment: "A request for the HID descriptor failed." Suggests that there is a communications error talking to the device. That it *sometimes* works suggests that there is some kind of intermittent connection. You may need to open up the laptop and check that whatever cables that come from the touchpad are clean and properly seated. You might want to use some alcohol cleaner on the cable/wire contacts.